# What happens if I run my event in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a small script in mysql and run it. It does create an event but what happens next? DO I still need to call it in php or does it run according to the schedule I declared within the even.

Here's my event

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT updatedoggytreat
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2011-07-01 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
  BEGIN
    UPDATE animal SET treat = treat + 6, bone = 5 WHERE breed = 'Bulldog' ;
    UPDATE animal SET treat = treat + 3, bone = bone + 4 WHERE breed  = 'small dog';
    UPDATE animal SET treat = treat + 6, bone = 5 WHERE breed = 'mix breed';
    UPDATE animal SET treat = 10, bone = 5 WHERE breed  = 'doberman';
    UPDATE animal SET treat = 15 WHERE breed  = 'sheepdog';
  END |

 DELIMITER ;
```

Do I still have to call this one in php or does it runs automatically based on the schedule I stated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: It would be kind of pointless to define an event with its schedule if you still had to call it manually...

Comment: Once the event has been created on the database, it's managed by the database, not by PHP or any other code

Comment: Thank for the kind comment sir. I'm just starting to learn mysql. I do know the basic but not all of them. That's why I'm asking. Funny that some users or so called "Helper/advisors" will downgrade or downvote a question just because it was too easy for them without taking any reason that this question might be too hard or even way too hard for the poster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

You do not have to call it manually using anything. They are scheduled events or "temporal triggers".

The SQL instance, that is, the server itself will manage it all. 
So long as your mysql is running, in accordance to the times that you set and periodicity etc, the event will trigger as you would expect.

You might want to do some research into what happens if it happens to be down at the time the scheduled event is meant to occur - that may be a configuration option.

Comment: Thanks....So it means that it will run on itself once I run it in mysql? Many Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick The SQL instance - the server itself will manage it all. So, yes. So long as your mysql is running.

Comment: I mean... in accordance to the times that you set, and periodicity etc. You might want to do some research into what happens if it happens to be down at the time the scheduled event is meant to occur - that may be a configuration option.

Comment: @Patrick No worries brother. Don't be afraid to hit that tick :) Also,  sorry for the downvotes...

Comment: Its nothing sir. Thanks for the help